# Nouveau display driver constantly crashing, other available drivers not able to display 2560x1080

Tags: nvidia, xorg, xrandr, nouveau

Apologies for not providing a perfect formatting for this post. I am still learning.

I have NVidia Quadro K1200 with Linux Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried to display the resolution of my main monitor at 2560x1080 with no success (only up to 1920x1080 is available). I have already tried the following approaches:

a) switched to NVidia X-Server driver to see if I could configure it to display 2560x1080, no success, only up to 1920x1080.

b) I have tried other available drivers by Ubuntu, no success, only up to 1920x1080.

c) Using X.org driver also fails, since resolution 2560x1080 is not available.

The frequent problem I was having previously (when it worked right after I installed) is that randomly the screen freezes and then I am no longer able to do anything (except for doing a hard reboot in the system).

Looking at the syslog, I found the following problems:

first case:

> chrome-pkjmikhjfekbpecnijapbekepjdoieci-Default.desktop[6241]: [28993:26:0616/091714.799688:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3415)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
> chrome-pkjmikhjfekbpecnijapbekepjdoieci-Default.desktop[6241]: [28993:26:0616/091714.799869:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3415)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
> chrome-pkjmikhjfekbpecnijapbekepjdoieci-Default.desktop[6241]: [28993:26:0616/091714.800004:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3415)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
> chrome-pkjmikhjfekbpecnijapbekepjdoieci-Default.desktop[6241]: [28993:26:0616/091714.800157:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3415)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
> chrome-pkjmikhjfekbpecnijapbekepjdoieci-Default.desktop[6241]: [28993:26:0616/091714.800382:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3415)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
> chrome-pkjmikhjfekbpecnijapbekepjdoieci-Default.desktop[6241]: [28993:26:0616/091714.800685:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3415)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
> chrome-pkjmikhjfekbpecnijapbekepjdoieci-Default.desktop[6241]: [28993:26:0616/091714.800831:ERROR:webrtc_video_engine.cc(3415)] Absent receive stream; ignoring clearing encoded frame sink for ssrc 0
> kernel: [69160.613955] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 4 [00ff8ad000 Xorg[6036]]
> kernel: [69160.613968] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: gr: GPC0/TPC3/MP trap: global 00000004 [MULTIPLE_WARP_ERRORS] warp 3e0009 [ILLEGAL_INSTR_ENCODING]
> kernel: [69160.613979] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: fault 00 [READ] at 0000000002d29000 engine 00 [GR] client 08 [GPC0/PE_2] reason 02 [PTE] on channel 4 [00ff8ad000 Xorg[6036]]
> kernel: [69160.613990] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: channel 4: killed
> kernel: [69160.613992] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
> kernel: [69160.613996] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
> kernel: [69160.614002] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: Xorg[6036]: channel 4 killed!

Second case:

> kernel: [48045.264513] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: fault 01 [WRITE] at 000000001dcac000 engine 00 [GR] client 0f [GPC0/PROP_0] reason 80 [] on channel 2 [00ff8f9000 Xorg[2704]]
> kernel: [48045.264524] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: channel 2: killed
> kernel: [48045.264526] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: runlist 0: scheduled for recovery
> kernel: [48045.264530] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: fifo: engine 0: scheduled for recovery
> kernel: [48045.264536] nouveau 0000:03:00.0: Xorg[2704]: channel 2 killed!

I have already tried the following:

a) downgrade to ubuntu 19.04 and 19.10 to see if problem persists (still persists)

b) tried other distributions (Mint, Xubuntu), no success, same problem

c) tried disabling HW acceleration in some browsers (Chrome and Firefox), since I saw some complaints from users in blogs saying that Chrome was the cause of the issue (no success).

d) Tried to use xrandr to configure and add a new mode, but it still throws an error when adding the mode:

> wrpires@wrpires-Precision-Tower-5810:~$ xrandr --addmode DP-1 2560x1080_68.00
> X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
> Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
> Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
> Serial number of failed request:  45
> Current serial number in output stream:  46

I believe I already have the latest drivers, and yet I am still getting these crashes.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: What is the make/model of your monitor and how is it connected to your PC? Update your question with the results of running `xrandr`. And regarding (d) did you run the correct `ctv` command, followed by the correct `xrandr --newmode` and THEN the `xrandr --addmode`? As described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by replacing the HDMI cable (DP adapter to HDMI) to a full DisplayPort cable.

After replacing the cable, the nvidia driver was able to go to the resolution supported by the monitor (29KW600 at 2560x1080).

The reason why I did not previously suspect that the problem was at the cable is that I am able to go at 2560x1080 resolution with existing HDMI cable using the X.org drivers (but they are constantly crashing the PC).